# React-Redux. Удалить элемент из массива

Tags: reactjs, redux

На сайте по самообучению задана такая задача:

```
 const immutableReducer = (state = [0,1,2,3,4,5], action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'REMOVE_ITEM':
      // don't mutate state here or the tests will fail
      return 
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const removeItem = (index) => {
  return {
    type: 'REMOVE_ITEM',
    index
  }
}

const store = Redux.createStore(immutableReducer);
```

и условие:

> "The reducer and action creator were modified to remove an item from
>   an array based on the index of the item. Finish writing the reducer so
>   a new state array is returned with the item at the specific index
>   removed.   The spread operator can be used here as well. Other useful
>   JavaScript methods include `slice()` and `concat()`."

Предполагаю, что ответ относительно простой, но уже два раза пролистал мануалы по этим операторам и ничего не приходит в голову.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Метод [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) возвращает новый массив, содержащий копию части
>   исходного массива.
>
> Метод [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) возвращает новый массив, состоящий из массива,
>   на котором он был вызван, соединённого с другими массивами и/или
>   значениями, переданными в качестве аргументов.

Если в методе `slice()` указано два параметра, то первый - это начальный элемент, второй - конечный элемент, ну или другими словами это промежуток.

Если в методе `slice()` указан указан один параметр - то начиная с указанного индекса и до конца массива (учитываем, что нумерация индексов начинается с `0`, поэтому там есть `+ 1`).

Собственно сам код будет выглядеть так:

```
const immutableReducer = (state = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'REMOVE_ITEM':
      return state.slice(0, action.index).concat(state.slice(action.index + 1));
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const removeItem = (index) => {
  return {
    type: 'REMOVE_ITEM',
    index
  }
}

const store = Redux.createStore(immutableReducer);
```

Ссылка на похожий ответ с пояснением: [Is this the correct way to delete an item using redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34582848/5275890). Из этого ответа я бы привел в качестве дополенния следующий текст:

> Никогда не мутируйте свое состояние `state`. Даже при том, что вы возвращаете
>   новый объект, вы все еще загрязняете старый объект. Это делает его
>   проблематичным при сравнении старого и нового состояний. Используйте
>   иммутабл методы, к которым как раз относится `slice()` и `concat()` (они возвращают новый массив в результате).